# Trying to denormalize the numpy array

Tags: python, arrays

Context: I had an array`x` which had values from range -100 to 400 after which i did a normalization operation that looks like this  `x = (x-x.min())/ (x.max()- x.min())`,After which i converted the array to `np.unit8`.Now the array is stored in `np.uint8` which stores values only between 0-255,

Question:What inverse operation i might do,so that i get the range of values -100 to 400.

Any suggestions would be helpful,Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
x = np.clip(x, -100, 400)
x = (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())
x = x * 255
x = np.uint8(x)
x = sitk.GetImageFromArray(x)
```

Comment: an explanation as to why the downvote would be nice,

Comment: using `x = (x-x.min())/ (x.max()- x.min())` results in values ranging from `0-1`. If you then convert to `uint8` you will only have 0 or 1 in your array (mostly `0` I guess). Am I missing something here, because it doesn't seem to be making much sense what you are describing

Comment: Are you doing a rescaling from the range `[0.0, 1.0]` to `[0, 255]`?

Comment: One second let me recheck.

Comment: Show the proper code doing this 'normalization', would help greatly to understand and eventually be able to provide an answer.

Comment: Im sorry ,I forgot to mention after the normalization i multiply it by 255,One second let me post the code

Comment: @Ryan Downvote is for the absolute lack of code shown, plus the fact that this is merely a basic math problem.

Comment: @GPhilo Got it.Thanks

Comment: Still woefully incomplete code...

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Thats the code im using ,You want to see the array ?

Comment: @Ryan an example array, imports, and then what you tried.

Comment: You don't expect to get the original array back, do you? That's impossible because you reduced an integer range of 500 down to an integer range of 256 and there's no way to recover the lost information.

Comment: But cant i maybe divide the array by  255 and then do the inverse of the the normalize operation to get the values in range -100 to 400 again?

Comment: @Ryan no.......

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Oh Okay,I got this all wrong.Thanks for the input

Comment: I know this is an old question but I think Ryan is right, why wouldn't he be able to do so? You can save the range and then denormalize with it again like stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512852/denormalization-of-numpy-matrix-is-not-correct).

Answer (score 0):

You could just store your normalized array as a new variable:

```
x_norm = (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())
```